# How to do drag in Protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor

I have requirement to crop an image. while cropping, i need to drag a rectangle up to image's full size, in order to get full image while uploading.I have added the screenshot below.[image]

I need to drag this rectangle to image's full width as given below[image]

How i will get the image's full size and drag up to the full size.Can we do this action through automation script? Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more info as: html sample, code sample, framework for image cropping?

Comment: There is a known issue with mouse actions and Chrome. It's been around for awhile. You can see it mentioned in the official docs  https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions. I've used `html-dnd` to get around it before but I'm not sure if it will work in this case. It's worth a try.